# is it good idea to use getter/setter methods to wrapping/unwrapping the java objects to Writable objects?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

More specifically, in hadoop MapReduce programs if you are using custom classes, the class needs to implement Writable interface. and all its members need to be writable e.g.

```
class WeatherData implements Writable{
     Text stationId;
     LongWritable timestamp;
     IntWritable temperature;

}
```

but since Text, LongWritable, IntWritable etc. classes are Writable wrapper classes for primitive data types. You can't do regular manipulations with them like arithmetic operations or string manipulation etc.

having getter setter methods like

```
 public String getStationId(){
     return this.stationId.toString();
 }

 public void setStationId(String stationID){
     this.stationId = new Text(stationID);
 }
```

would be beneficial, as the outside world can treat these members as regular java classes but internally they will be stored as objects of writable classes.

My question is whether it is good coding practice or not. what are potential pitfalls with having such getter/setter methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem like a good practice to me. Have a look at the [Writable Interface Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html). All you really need to do is implement the `readFields()` and `write()` methods. (Your class members do not need to be writable themselves - See the example in the documentation.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking of Writable as similar to Serializable. That's where the confusion came from.